# ExpressJS middleware vs logic

Tags: node.js, express, routes, structure, middleware

What is the best way to structure the logic in an ExpressJS API.

So lets say I want to create a register and login function, and lets say I want a user to be logged in when he is successfully registered.
Now there are different ways I can achieve this, my question is then essentially: **Which method is best and why?**

### METHOD 1

Everything is middleware:

```
router.post('/path', someMiddleware, register, login, function(req, res){
    //You are registered and logged in.
});
```

So here both the register and login is treated as middleware, with both of them ending with a call to `next()`. This also results in the best reusability, because I can call either login and/or register again in any other express routing.

---

### METHOD 2

Register is middleware and calls login (which is now just a standard function):

```
router.post('/path', someMiddleware, register, function(req, res){
    //You are registered and logged in.
});
```

So here register is still middleware, but just before calling `next()` it calls `login()` which in this case is not middleware. The problem here is that if user that is already registered wants to login, should I create a hybrid login function that is also middleware and just call it in that specific post request?

---

### METHOD 3

Logic is not in middleware and gets called in the wrapper:

```
router.post('/path', someMiddleware, funcWrapper(register, login), function(req, res){
    //You are registered and logged in.
});
```

and then (in pseudo):

```
funcWrapper(actions...){
    foreach actions
        action()
}
```

Here logic and middleware are split, there is a wrapper that loops through all the functions that are passed in as parameter (in this case register and login)

---

### Just a last question:

If I haven't asked enough questions, I have a last one. Is it better practice to end all express routing calls with

```
..., function(req, res){
    //response
});
```

or with

```
..., lastMiddleware);
```

and then in the lastMiddleware there is some response

Comment: I would think registering is done through `/register`, and logging in is done through `/login` (i.e. separate routes for each action), where `/register` would redirect to `/login` once the user has successfully registered.

Comment: but what if I want to register and login in one request. Because I don't want the user to register and then type in his details again. Like reddit for example. I registered and bam I was logged in

Comment: I assume that you run some sort of code to log a user in (pass username and password to a function, get "okay" or "not okay" back). If you separate that code (say into a `User` class) you can call it from wherever you like.